# Storing data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to read my data depending on an action button, but I cant access the data in other expressions. I have tried different ways, but none worked.

```
S.Data <- observeEvent(input$RawGo,{

    read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/", green.only = T)
})
```

An other way:

```
    observeEvent(input$RawGo,{

    S.Data <- read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/", green.only = T)
})
```

An other way:

```
        observeEvent(input$RawGo,{

    S.Data <- reactive({read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/", green.only = T)
    })
})
```

Nothing worked.

Complete code

```
  output$RawButton <- renderUI({
if(!is.null(input$File1)){

  if(input$imageS != "Other"){
    actionButton(inputId = "RawGo", label = "Read data", icon = icon("upload"))
  } else{
    actionButton(inputId = "RawGo", label = "Read data, if import is correctly", icon = icon("upload"))
  }

}

})


S.Data <- reactive({input$RawGo;isolate({
targets = readTargets(input$File1$datapath, sep=input$sep)

  if(input$imageS != "Other" & input$datatype == "One"){
      read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/", green.only = T)
  }else if(input$imageS != "Other" & input$datatype == "Two"){
      read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/")
  }else if(input$imageS == "Other" & input$datatype == "One" & input$RawCBack == "Y"){
      read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, 
                  path = "Raw data/",
                  columns=list(G=input$RawProbe, Gb=input$RawBack),
                  green.only = T)
  }else if(input$imageS == "Other" & input$datatype == "One" & input$RawCBack == "N"){
      read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, 
                  path = "Raw data/",
                  columns=list(G=input$RawProbe),
                  green.only = T)
  }else if(input$imageS == "Other" & input$datatype == "Two" & input$RawCBack == "Y"){
      read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, 
                  path = "Raw data/",
                  columns=list(G=input$RawProbe, Gb=input$RawBack, R=input$RawProbeR,Rb=input$RawBackR))
    }else if(input$imageS == "Other" & input$datatype == "Two" & input$RawCBack == "N"){
        read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, 
                  path = "Raw data/",
                  columns=list(G=input$RawProbe, R=input$RawProbeR))
    }
  })
})
#--------------------------------Preprocessing---------------------------
output$PrePMis<- renderUI({

D.Data <- S.Data()    

  })
})
```

output$PrePMis is in an other tab. The code is independent from the button and is performed, when I go to the tab with output$PrePMis

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe `S.Data<-reactive({input$RawGo;isolate(read.maimages(files = targets$FileName, source = input$imageS, 
                  path = "Raw data/", green.only = T))})` and then with `S.Data()` you can call the data in other contexts. No need of an `observeEvent` context, if you need that the `read.maimages` is only performed when the `RawGo` button is pressed.

Comment: Your suggestion is not the way I wanted.The code is performed evertime, when I call S.Data(). I wanted to use that code once and store the data. Read.maimages is a quite time consuming function.

Comment: You should describe better what you are trying to achieve, provide a reproducible example and explain clearly what you want. How do you expect that someone could help you if you just say "Your suggestion is not the way I wanted". What that is supposed to mean? It gives errors? It does other things? Please, explain if you want someone to help you.

Comment: Sorry. Hit the enter button and didnt know, that it will be posted

Comment: `S.Data()` is not performed every time, but only when `input$RawGo` changes. If `RawGo` is a button, that means that the calculation is carried only when the button is pressed. See `?isolate` and/or some shiny tutorial.

Comment: Complete code updated

Comment: You have two `RawGo` elements and this leads to problems. Try to remove the condition in the `renderUI` part (leaving the button label fixed) and see if it works.

Comment: The code is still not performed when I click the button. The code is performed when i click the button and then try to save it with for example D.Data <- S.Data().